# hierarchical query in mongodb programming

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, database

I am working on some project.In that it will store data in hierarchical manner.So that I can query and update from root to any immediate children or any other part of tree.It is a type of referral system.

But I am confused how to store the data in mongodb collections for such queries. Please help me in making schema of database like referencing etc.

[image]

for example in above case :

Each and every documents is containing some attributes to be updated.
I have to store total at "C" of each and every descendents.But how should I do that ?

From "A" I have to update every document value.

Please help me.How should I make its schema for easy updation ?

Comment: Have you looked at the mongodb docs? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: yes @Paul I have seen it.Should I store "children : [ ]" and "parent" of each node ?

Comment: @Paul should I store "parent" and "ancestors" in each user document ?

Comment: Depends on what queries you're planning to do. Also, if your architecture allows it, you should consider a graph db like Neo4J for this. It makes a this a much more natively supported kind of problem.